# is it possible to trim last three characters in string with selected row in selected column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i used this query for trim function for selected rows last 3 values

```
select substr(detail,0,length(detail)-3) from address where  detail_no=1;
```

Above query trims the all rows last 3 characters. 
But i want to trim the selected rows character

```
for example. row 1 text added
             row 2 last value
             row 3 end value
```

i want to trim only row 2's last 3 character

any one explain how to use that query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE` for this.
Btw, your query seems to have a few problems I guess, you need to write the column names before the tablename.

This may solve your problem. You have to put your column's name instead of `rownumber`

```
select case a.rownumber
          when 2 then substr (a.detail, 0, length (a.detail) - 3)
          else a.detail
       end, a.*
  from address a
 where a.detail_no = 1
```

Comment: thank you for the query i will check and let you know

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2208467/yigitalp-ertem @Yigitalp Ertem thank you for your query its working fine but this query shows selected column name but i also want all columns including that trim column

Comment: @vasanth, then you can write other columns' names after the case statement. I don't know your column names but I edited my post with some dummy column names.

Comment: @ Yigitalp Ertem thank you again i'm not asked about this but in some where i saw .* function is used for selected column name first and other column names are come next. i dont know exactly its correct functionality or not. i think you know .if its correct please update query ...

Comment: @vasanth, you're right. I updated the query with the usage of .*